# regular expression mismatch in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a block of html code in variable card in js file.I caught regular expression not match in card variable error.All single and double quotes matches.What I did wrong in html block.Is any typo error.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.one_time_popup = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
var celeType=Drupal.settings.one_time_popup.celeType;
 card="<div class=\'cardTemplate-aniv\'> 
 <p class=\'bir-anniv-wishes\'>Happy Birthday and Successful Anniversary</p>
 <p id=\'aspirian-name\'>"+userName+"</p>
 <img src=\'"+Drupal.settings.publicpath+"/Birthday_Images/birthdayTemplate1.jpg\' style=\'width:250px;height:230px;\'>
 <img src=\'"+Drupal.settings.publicpath+"/Anniversary_Images/"+anniversaryCount+"Anniversary.jpg\' style=\'width:250px;height:250px;\'>
</div>";
 }
};
}(jQuery));
```

I have one more temmplate

```
 cardTemplate1 = "<div class=\'cardTemplate\'><span class=\'birthdayImage\'></span><p class=\'wishes\'>Happy Birthday <span id=\'aspirian-name\'>"+userName+"</span> !</p><img src=\'"+Drupal.settings.publicpath+"/Birthday_Images/birthdayTemplate1.jpg\'></div>";
```

which shows regular expression mismatch without escape single quotes

Comment: Please update your answer with more code, including the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiline string literals in double quotes. If you have ES6 you can use backticks to have a multiline template string. See [creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the single quotes `'`.

Comment: What error? Please include this information in your question!